# Parsing (partially) non-uniform text blocks in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, sed, awk

I have a file with a few blocks that look like this in a file (and in a variable, at this point in the program).

```
Vlan2 is up, line protocol is up
  ....
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255^M
  ....
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters 49w5d
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  ....
  L3 out Switched: ucast: 17925 pkt, 23810209 bytes mcast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes
     33374 packets input, 13154058 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 926 broadcasts (0 IP multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     3094286 packets output, 311981311 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 interface resets
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

Here's a second block, to show you how the blocks can slightly vary:

```
port-channel86 is down (No operational members)
  ...
  reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  ...
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters 31w2d
  ...
  RX
    147636 unicast packets  0 multicast packets  0 broadcast packets
    84356 input packets  119954232 bytes
    0 jumbo packets  0 storm suppression packets
    0 runts  0 giants  0 CRC  0 no buffer
    0 input error  0 short frame  0 overrun   0 underrun  0 ignored
    0 watchdog  0 bad etype drop  0 bad proto drop  0 if down drop
    0 input with dribble  0 input discard
    0 Rx pause
  TX
    147636 unicast packets  0 multicast packets  0 broadcast packets
    84356 output packets  119954232 bytes
    0 jumbo packets
    0 output error  0 collision  0 deferred  0 late collision
    0 lost carrier  0 no carrier  0 babble  0 output discard
    0 Tx pause
  0 interface resets
```

I want to pick out certain data elements from each block, which may or may not exist in each block. For example, in the first block I posted I may want to know that there are 0 runts, 0 input errors and 0 overrun. In the second block, I might want to know that there are 0 jumbo packets, collisions, etc. If a given query isn't in the block, it's acceptable to just return na, as this is designed to be processed uniformly.

Each block is structured in a similar way to the two I posted; newlines and spaces delimiting some entries, commas delimiting others.

I have a few ideas as to how this might work. I'm unaware if there is any kind of "look back" function in Perl, but I could attempt to look for the field names (runts, "input errors", etc) and then grab the previous integer; that seems like it would be the most elegant solution for this, but I'm unsure if it's possible.

Currently, I'm doing this in Perl. Each "block" that I'm processing is actually several of these blocks (separated by double newlines). It doesn't have to be done in a single regular expressions; I believe it can be done by applying several regular expressions per block. Performance is not really a factor, as this script will run maybe once per hour.

My goal is to get all of this into a .csv file (or some other data format that's easily graphable) in an automated fashion.

Any ideas?

Edit: example output in CSV as I mentioned, which would be written line by line (for multiple entries like this) to a file as the end result. If a particular entry isn't found in the block, it is marked na in the corresponding line:

```
interface_name,txload,rxload,last_clearing,input_queue,output_drops,runts,....
vlan2,1,1,49w5d,0-75-0-0,0,0,....
port-channel86,1,1,31w2d,na,na,0,...
```

Comment: Can you post example output?

Comment: Done. I hope that answers the question.

Comment: It's impossible to extrapolate the general layout of your input from a single sample of a block. Why not reduce your block size to something that just represents the real block and then posting 5 or so blocks so we can get an idea of in what ways the format might vary between blocks?

Comment: I posted a second block. They're all like that output style, but with different fields. Is this sufficient?

Comment: No. Post about 3 more input blocks, update your output to show how it should look given that input, and explain why. Again, it'd be very helpful if you can reduce each block to, say 5 or 6 lines that REPRESENT your real blocks so we don't have to read through a lot of irrelevant data to try to help you.

Comment: This **can't be done**. The blocks have no clear structured format, and are ill suited for processing with automated tools. There are *some* structures that could be extracted (`X is Y`-phrases, `(NUMBER WORDS COMMA?)+`) but I wouldn't be able to extract anything in a reliable way, and definitely not without false positives.

Comment: This can easy be solved using SNMP to read your data.
Now you have to log in to the router, get the data, convert it.
With SNMP you can get data direct and you can covert it easy to what you like.
Do a google search for SNMP cisco switch ODI

Comment: @amon I totally disagree.  It would be very difficult to do it in a single Regular expression, but you could easily do it with multiple, depending on what information you're trying to pull out.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan I can do it with multiple regular expressions.

Comment: @Jotne: I'll look into SNMP to do this; that's an option in this environment. If I end up using that as a solution, I'll post a separate question and ask you to answer it so you can get credit.

Answer (score 1):

Simple hash of properties and numbers.

```
sub extract {
    my ($block) = @_;
    my %r;
    while ($block =~ /(?<num>\d+) \s (?<name>[A-Za-z\s]+)/gmsx) {
        my $name = $+{name};
        my $num = $+{num};
        $name =~ s/\A \s+//msx;
        $name =~ s/\s+ \z//msx;
        $r{$name} = $num;
    }
    return %r;
}

my $block = <<'';
Vlan2 is up, line protocol is up
⋮

my $block2 = <<'';
port-channel86 is down (No operational members)
⋮

use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
print Dumper {extract $block};
print Dumper {extract $block2};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a single regex could do it, nor would I want to support it if it could.

Using multiple regexes, you could easily use something like:

```
(\d+) runts
(\d+) input errors
...etc...
```

A simple array of property names and a loop could solve this pretty quickly and with very little fuss.

If you can strip down the input to smaller chunks with some preprocessing, you would be less likely to get false positives.

Comment: A single regex to do it isn't needed; multiple queries would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it in awk, but this needs lots of tweak to be perfect.
But again, use SNMP.

```
awk '{
    printf $1
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i" "$(i+1)~/Input queue:/) printf ",%s",$(i+2)
        if ($i~/runts/) printf ",%s",$(i-1)
        if ($i~/multicast,/) printf ",%s",$(i-1)
    }
    print ""
}' RS="swapped out" file
```